# Slim Framework : unable to use JWT token

Tags: php, authentication, composer-php, jwt, slim

I am working on a slim REST API and I want to secure it with JWT Token. I try a lot of tutorials and I am anable to make things work.

I use :
slim 4.*
slim/psr7 0.6.0
tuupola/slim-jwt-auth ^3.4
tuupola/cors-middleware ^1.1

Ubuntu 19.10 and Xampp

I have have 2 routes (POST /login and GET /api/test)
I want to be able to use the /login route without token and the other one with a token.
So I wrote :

```php
$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api",
    "secret" => getenv ("SPROUTCH_TOKEN"),
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    },
]));
```

In that case nothing is secure so I tried this :

```
$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "secret" => getenv ("SPROUTCH_TOKEN"),
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    },
]));
```

And of course I can't access anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "In that case nothing is secure" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proble was just that the "path" key takes only absolute path